# How to validate file extension with Multer middleware

Tags: node.js, multer, file-type

I use Multer for uploading file or images. Problem is that it is impossible to validate the real file extension.

Example: If someone rename `filename.exe` to `filename.png`, then it is still validate to upload.

Can you suggest me the solution to handle this issue? Thanks

I used like this but need verify real ext of files

```
fileFilter: async function (req, file, callback) {
    var ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
    if(ext !== '.png' && ext !== '.jpg' && ext !== '.gif' && ext !== '.jpeg' && ext !== '.zip') {
        return callback(new Error('Only images and zip are allowed'));
    }
    // I want next function to validate real ext of files here. 
    callback(null, true); 
  },
```

Answer (score 23):

Starting with Multer 2.x.x You can check for both the extension and the MIME type of the uploaded parameter. Here is a sample code.

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: './uploadedContent',
    filename: function(_req, file, cb){
      
      cb(null,file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    } 
  });
var upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: {
        fields: 5,
        fieldNameSize: 50, // TODO: Check if this size is enough
        fieldSize: 20000, //TODO: Check if this size is enough
        // TODO: Change this line after compression
        fileSize: 15000000, // 150 KB for a 1080x1080 JPG 90
    },
    fileFilter: function(_req, file, cb){
        checkFileType(file, cb);
    }
}).single('postPicture');
function checkFileType(file, cb){
  // Allowed ext
  const filetypes = /jpeg|jpg|png|gif/;
  // Check ext
  const extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
  // Check mime
  const mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);

  if(mimetype && extname){
    return cb(null, true);
  } else {
    return cb(null, false);
  }
}
```

Don't forget to check your file permissions too. You don't want the uploaded file to be executed somehow.
Sadly the latest npm release is 1.4.3 where the Multer mime type is based on the type property that comes from the client. That property at least in windows is dependent of the file extension, not on the file content.

Comment: You can only do this with Multer 2.x.x release but the currently npm available release 1.4.3 relies only on what is in the header regarding the file type. And is based in most systems in the file extension. So currently checking mimetype won't help you iwth the validation. You must use file-type to do it

Comment: What you say @JulioSpinelli is really important to think

Answer (score 10):

There are two steps:

1. Filtering by mime type provided by multer on `fileFilter` options
2. Filtering the real mime type from the file buffer/stream using [file-type](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type).

Define whitelist mime type:

```js
const whitelist = [
  'image/png',
  'image/jpeg',
  'image/jpg',
  'image/webp'
]
```

Example of the first step:

```js
const upload = multer({
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination: 'public/uploads/',
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      const name = slugify(file.originalname, { lower: true })
      cb(null, `${new Date().getTime()}-${name}`)
    },
  }),
  fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
    if (!whitelist.includes(file.mimetype)) {
      return cb(new Error('file is not allowed'))
    }

    cb(null, true)
  }
})
```

Example of the second step:

```js
const FileType = require('file-type')

// ....
// first step
// ....

/**
 * Second step
 */
app.use('store', upload.single('image'), async (req, res, next) => {
  const meta = await FileType.fromFile(req.file.path)

  if (!whitelist.includes(meta.mime)) {
    return next(new Error('file is not allowed'))
  }

  res.json({
    file: req.file,
    body: req.body,
  })
})
```

I tried to rename a `document.pdf` -> `document.png` and it passed the first check but got caught on the second one.

Comment: This is the best answer because the 2 step process provides the most security. Just as a side note, the FileType cannot be checked in the `fileFilter` function because the file (or the buffer) is not yet available at that step.

Comment: file-type now requires projects to be pure ESM. BOOOOO

Comment: What do you do with files that were uploaded but didn't pass the 2nd test? Do you run a CRON job to delete them from time to time?

Comment: You can actually remove the file directly before throwing exception on the 2nd test

Answer (score 4):

Basically what you need is something which can verify the extension with original file type.

Copied from a blog

```
    var upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
    if (file.mimetype == "image/png" || file.mimetype == "image/jpg" || file.mimetype == "image/jpeg") {
      cb(null, true);
    } else {
      cb(null, false);
      return cb(new Error('Only .png, .jpg and .jpeg format allowed!'));
    }
  }
});
```

[Blog Link](https://www.positronx.io/multer-file-type-validation-tutorial-with-example/)

If this doesn't work for you, consider using a separate module which verify file type from buffer data.