# How to get an image through an Axios POST request to node.js backend?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to send a image from a react front end to a node.js backend using axios, with help from this post: [How do you send images to node js with Axios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39663961/how-do-you-send-images-to-node-js-with-axios) I managed to get it from the frontend to the backend, but when I `console.log` the `req.files` and the `req.body` it's `undefined` or empty. I can't figure out how to fix it. Can anyone help me?

Here is the code for the `app.js` React frontend:

```
import "./App.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState("");
  function handleImage(e) {
    console.log(e.target.files);
    setImage(e.target.files[0]);
  }
  function handleApi() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("image", image);
    console.log(formData)
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:3001/users/editprofile/1", formData, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      });
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="file" name="file" onChange={handleImage} />
      <button onClick={handleApi}>submit</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and this is the node.js back end:

```
router.post("/editprofile/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  console.log(req.files)
  console.log(req.body)
  //console.log(req)
  //const { pfp } = req.files;

  // if (pfp) {
  //   await pfp.mv(`${__dirname}/images/profile_pictures/pfp_${id}}`);
  // }

  //Would make the code "save" by not allowing any uploads at allz`
  //if (/^image/.test(image.mimetype)){
  //    console.log("not an image");
  //    return res.sendStatus(400);
  //}

  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

When I log just the `req` I get a response to the Axios is sending something to the backend and when I look into the network and console in the browser I get the following things:

The network tab in the browser:
[image]

The console in the browser:
[image]

Thanks in advance for the help!!

Comment: read the answer there: [_On node js server make sure to use some middle-ware which handles multipart requests. I used multer._](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44945988/4321299)

Comment: I treid to do that, but I don't unerstand it XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on the server side, you're missing a form/multipart request processing middleware.

The usual tool is [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)

So, on your route, you need to add upload middleware, then you can access file via `req.file` (or `req.files`, if multiple files, check the docs).

Before that, you need to setup upload middleware where you setup location (destination), filename and mimetype checker.

Also, there you can read `req.params.id` and use it for filename, and also add image filter, not in the route.

Try this:

router:

```
const myUploadMiddleware = require('./upload');

router.post("/editprofile/:id", myUploadMiddleware, async (req, res) => {
  
  console.log('editprofile', req.body, req.file);

  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

upload middleware:

```
const multer = require('multer');


const storage = multer.diskStorage({

    // my destination here
    destination: function(req, file, cb) {

        cb(null, `${__dirname}/images/profile_pictures/`)
    },
    // my custom filename here
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {

        //const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9)
        //cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + uniqueSuffix)

        const id = req.params.id;

        cb(null, `pfp_${id}`);
    }
});

// my mimetype check here
const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {

    if (!file.mimetype.includes('image')) {
        return cb(new Error('not an image'));
    }
    cb(null, true);
};


// also field name here image has to correspond to image on the frontend
// formData.append("image", image);

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    fileFilter
}).single('image');


module.exports = upload;
```

Comment: Thank you this helped!! the only problem I'm having now is that if I added a .jpg it won't go further in the code because of that it thinks it is a jpeg any solutions for that? ans it won't addd the file exxtention but `path.extname(file.originalname)` helps with that!!

Comment: yeah, you can tweak it depending on your needs. not sure what you mean, but you can check mimetypes, and create your whitelist, maybe something like this: [How to validate file extension with Multer middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60408575/how-to-validate-file-extension-with-multer-middleware)